# Call to undefined function json_encode(),ctype_digit() on PHP7, ubuntu

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, yii2

i use `Yii2 , OS ubuntu 16.0.4 , PHP7 , Apache , MySql`

i think this problem from php7

how to enable or install json_encode for php and ctype_digit for mysql?

i have this error:

> Call to undefined function yii\web\json_encode()
>
> Call to undefined function yii\db\mysql\ctype_digit()

phpInfo:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path   /etc/php/7.0/apache2
Loaded Configuration File   /etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files     /etc/php/7.0/apache2/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed    /etc/php/7.0/apache2/conf.d/20-mbstring.ini
```

about json i only find this on phpinfo:

```
JSON    Jakub Zelenka, Omar Kilani, Scott MacVicar
```

Comment: Can you describe more ? What's actually you are trying , what are the methods you tried.. etc ?

Comment: Please, post some code.

Comment: im run only Yii2  on new server. i think this problem from PHP7

Comment: i install php7 , apache. mysql from this learn: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: `sudo apt-get install php7.0-json`

Comment: @DanFromGermany i use this command Result:=> root@euve858129:~# sudo apt-get install php7.0-json
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
php7.0-json is already the newest version (7.0.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Comment: @DanFromGermany after run this comman , i restart Apache , but dont fix my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Enable json encode in php.ini file in /etc/php/php.ini. 
In this case, you'd need to uncomment the 'extension=json.so' line.

Comment: i have 4 folder on this address: /etc/php/7.0  (apache2 , cli , fpm , mods-available) , on ((apache2 , cli , fpm) i have php.ini file

Comment: <?php phpinfo(); ?> this will give the location of ini file.

Comment: i see this on phpinfo: Configuration File (php.ini) Path  /etc/php/7.0/apache2
Loaded Configuration File  /etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files  /etc/php/7.0/apache2/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed  /etc/php/7.0/apache2/conf.d/20-mbstring.ini

Comment: After you installed the package you need to enable it, Sucharitha gave you the answer and the file you have to edit is `/etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini`.

Comment: Even better, make a new file `/etc/php/7.0/apache2/conf.d/10-json.ini` and put in `extension=json.so`

Comment: @DanFromGermany why dont enable any extention on my php?